# jpg images are shown in iphone simulator but not in iPhone test device

Tags: iphone, ios, image, jpeg

i'm sorry for my english.
i'm new in iphone development and happens to me a strange things.

I have a set of jpg images to show in a table view. When i test the app in iphone simulator everything is ok and work properly but when built and run the same code in iphone test device the same images aren't displayed.

Another strange behavior is that with a set of png images instead of jpg are shown perfectly in simulator like as in iphone test device.

Anyone can suggest me a solution?

I detect the name of image to load from a json file. This is the code that i use to show the image:

```
UIImageView *immaginePiadina = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:immagineValueRect];
[immaginePiadina setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[item objectForKey:@"immagine"]]];
```

where [item objectForKey:@"immagine"] is an element of my json file like this:

```
"nome": "66",
"immagine": "pianetapiadabufalavesuviani",
"prezzo": "€ 7,50",
"nomeingrediente": [
                  "bufala",
                  "vesuviani"
                  ]
```

How you can see i refer to the image with only the name of the file and without the file extension. I did it in this way to show image retina, it's wrong?

I exclude that i wrote a different case sensitive name because the png set works properly.

thanks a lot!!

Comment: in the simulator its not that strict in calling images by using their names. lets say you have imagenamed.PNG in the simulator you can call it like this  [UIImage named:@"imagename.png"] and it will return to you the image you wanted, but in the device you have to be more specific if you want to call the image you have to use [UIImage named@"imagename.PNG"] see the extension is different

Comment: please post your code to add the image

Comment: Smells like you've referred to an image with a particular name like animage.png, where case sensitivity is not matching it to anImage.png.  The simulator's file system is not case sensitive - the device's is.

Comment: @ManuelRagazzini use .png instead of .jpg image, because many time jpg image not display in divice.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD thanks a lot for your reply but... so is simply that? There isn't an explanation? It seems strange because in UIImage class reference there is a box with supported format and jpeg/jpg are supported. Anyway thank you. The fact that one of your reputation have the same problems I'm consoled :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem using the following code:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[item objectForKey:@"immagine"] ofType:@"jpg"];
NSLog(@"%@",path);
UIImage* theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

I don't know the reason but in this way i haven't any problem to display jpg in my iPhone test device. Maybe because NSBundle specify also the extension of the file.

Thanks @David-h that directed me in the right way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly two separate issues that need separation, here is how to solve your problem.

First write a method using the NSFileManager, that given a file path verifies a file exists and has a size greater than 0. Insert a call to this everywhere you fail to open an image. If you use "imageNamed" then get the path to the bundle and create the path. If this method fails to find an image, fix it.

Second, the image decoding is different for the simulator and the device - the simulator uses the full OSX libraries. So take one image that fails to open and move it somewhere. Open it in Preview and export it using the same name but with png+alpha format. Change your code to expect a png not a jpg, and retest. Make sure you still use the first method to insure the file is there.

Once you get one success you can try other options, like using Preview exported jpegs. The reason this should work is that all of these image formats permit a huge range of options all of which iOS does not support.

Given that the current format us the problem, you can script changes using the "sips" program, which is what Preview uses.

Answer (score 0):

Check the extensions of your images. If you write .PNG, in the simulator is Ok, but not in the device.